# How can I read large filesizes in Ada?

Tags: ada, filesize

I've written an Ada program which encrypts files. It reads them block by block to conserve memory on the target machine. Unfortunately Ada's Directories library reads filesizes in a Long_Integer, limiting the read to almost 2GB files. When trying to read files over 2GB, the program fails at runtime getting a stack overflow error.

The documentation for it [here](http://www.martin.dowie.btinternet.co.uk/Directories/adabrowse/ada-directories.html#255_9) is the origin of my understanding above. How can I read a filesize into a type I define myself? One I can make requiring something like 25 bytes to increase the cap to 100GB.

Comment: You don't need 25 bytes to hold numbers of that size; 8 bytes (64 bits) is more than enough.

Comment: The Ada standard's definition is `type File_Size is range 0 .. `*implementation-defined*`;`. GNAT, at least in the version I have, has `File_Size'Last = 9223372036854775807`. What compiler are you using? And are you sure it's a stack overflow? That's not the error I'd expect. Try `Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Ada.Directories.File_Size'Image(Ada.Directories.File_Size'Last));`

Comment: Looking at the source of GNAT GPL 2012, `adaint.c` says in `__gnat_stat_to_attr()` "st_size may be 32 bits, or 64 bits which is converted to long. We don't return a useful value for files larger than 2 gigabytes in either case." What it actually means is "We don't bother to check whether the OS-reported file size will fit in a 32-bit result, we just assign it anyway." On Mac OS X this throws away the top 32 bits of the 64-bit result, and may give an apparently negative result. I think you may have to read the file size via `stat(2)` (or the equivalent on your OS).

Comment: @SimonWright: You're right; on my system, `File_Size` is 64 bits, but the `Size()` function's result discards all but the low-order 32 bits. This is a bug in GNAT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just posted [GCC bug 55119](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55119) on this.

While you're waiting (!), the code below works on Mac OS X Mountain Lion. On Windows, it's more complicated; see `adainclude/adaint.{c,h}`.

The Ada spec:

```
with Ada.Directories;
package Large_Files is

   function Size (Name : String) return Ada.Directories.File_Size;

end Large_Files;
```

and body (copied in part from `Ada.Directories`):

```
with GNAT.OS_Lib;
with System;
package body Large_Files is

   function Size (Name : String) return Ada.Directories.File_Size
   is
      C_Name : String (1 .. Name'Length + 1);
      function C_Size (Name : System.Address) return Long_Long_Integer;
      pragma Import (C, C_Size, "large_file_length");
   begin
      if not GNAT.OS_Lib.Is_Regular_File (Name) then
         raise Ada.Directories.Name_Error
           with "file """ & Name & """ does not exist";
      else
         C_Name (1 .. Name'Length) := Name;
         C_Name (C_Name'Last) := ASCII.NUL;
         return Ada.Directories.File_Size (C_Size (C_Name'Address));
      end if;
   end Size;

end Large_Files;
```

and the C interface:

```
/* large_files_interface.c */

#include <sys/stat.h>

long long large_file_length (const char *name)
{
  struct stat statbuf;
  if (stat(name, &statbuf) != 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return (long long) statbuf.st_size;
  }
}
```

You might need to use `struct stat64` and `stat64()` on other Unix systems.

Compile the C interface as normal, then add `-largs large_files_interface.o` to your gnatmake command line.

EDIT: on Mac OS X (and Debian), which are x86_64 machines, `sizeof(long)` is 8 bytes; so the comment in `adaint.c` is misleading and `Ada.Directories.Size` can return up to 2**63-1.